# jquery get is not a function when trying to a specific table row

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to select item '2' using .get()

My code is:

```
alert( $('table tr').find('td').get(2).html() );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HgB4/)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use .eq(2) instead of get.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3HgB4/1/

```
alert( $('table tr').find('td').eq(2).html() );
```

or even better

```
$('table tr:first td:eq(2)').html()
```

Comment: because `.get` returns the DOM element and not the jQuery object

Comment: Indeed, the function `.html()` does not exist on the DOM object but does on the jQuery object. If you want to use `.get()` then you have to do `.innerHTML` instead of `.html()`